# Table with thead and tfoot incorrect layout when printed in chrome

Tags: html, css, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer for pdf generation on linux alpine. I use the `thead` `tbody` `tfoot` trick to get proper headers and footers on each page.

I noticed some weird behavior with how chrome and chromium does layout when printing. Namely, skipping the first page when rendering a table.

Here's a repro (tested for Chrome 73.0.3683.75 on Ubuntu 18.04, might be important since this repro was a bit hard to recreate and font-rendering might affect layout).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    thead {
      display: table-header-group;
    }
    
    tfoot {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    html,
    body,
    table,
    tr,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead style="background:#fcc">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="height: 231px">head</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="background:#cfc">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>widow</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="background:#ccf">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="height:231px">foot</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice that when loading this page and hitting ctrl+p the table begins rendering on the second page of the document https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M88A.png. I would expect it to start in the first page. Is there a css rule for this, something like `page-break-inside: do-it-please-instead-of-messing-up-my-table`?

Edit: Forgot a setting, use Margins `None` to repro the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKWNg.png

Also, a tangential issue:
Removing the second table row, `<tr><td>widow</td></tr>`, shows another unexpected rendering artifact: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVP4H.png. Here, the `tbody` begins to render on the first page but pushes the `tfoot` to the second page. I would like the `tbody` to break in this case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have reported a bug to the chromium team for this:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962435#c13

Update - now marked as fixed (havent tested though):
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962435#c24

Unfortunately (but perhaps unsurprisingly) it's not really a priority. I ended up swapping puppeteer for openhtmltopdf which handles running headers and footers a bit better.

Also made a wrapper so that people can use it directly in a microservice environment: https://github.com/modfin/betterpress

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. There is a nice workarround for it.
As soon as you create a td with a rowspan it works fine.
look into the sniplet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    thead {
      display: table-header-group;
    }
    
    tfoot {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    html,
    body,
    table,
    tr,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead style="background:#fcc">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="height: 231px">head</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="background:#cfc">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 0px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 0px"><td style="width: 0px"></td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>widow</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="background:#ccf">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="height:231px">foot</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```